# How to catch an exception thrown by a function assigned to onload in javascript

Tags: javascript

How can I catch the Exception "my exception"? Surrounding the second instruction with a try catch doesn't work.

```
var fileReader = new FileReader();
fileReader.onload = (e) => {
    throw new Error("my exception")
};
fileReader.readAsText(myFile);
```

Comment: You don't. You can only catch it within the `onload` function itself. It's going to execute asynchronously *sometime later*, by which time the surrounding context is long gone.

Comment: Use promises and don't `throw` exceptions from asynchronous callbacks.

Comment: `try`/`catch` would work, but you need to surround the `throw` statement itself, not the statement that installs the `onload` handler.